Rest call failed with client error, status code 404 in ADF. But I can see the date through postman
I am trying to connect share point through graph api using service principal. I have set up a rest dataset in the copy activity and set the base url as https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/ and gave the required relative url. And I am getting an adf error:

I tried the same through postman using the same access token and URL and I am able to see the data as required. I have setup the linked service for rest API using the service principal and the connection was successful.

When trying the same with ADF, it throws an error. Anybody could help me understand what the problem is? What should I do differently?

Is it the same token you are using in both(service principal and postman) cases?

Per your error message it appears that parameters passed in relative URL are not recognizing it.
A relative URL is optional, you can pass the parameter in baseurl itself using if else expression. I have implemented a similar use case. Here are the steps:

in the base URL (parameterize the value) expression be like (@if(equal(variable('continuationUrl'),'NA'), pipeline().parmeters.source_baseURL,variable('continuationUrl'))
In case you are doing pagination rule to get the latest URL.
Pass authorization in additional header.

